# Close .exe File using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, exe, spawn

I am using this node js code to run App.exe file that contains an infinite loop. I pass input and get output from App.exe.

```
var bat = null;
app.post("/api/run", function(req, res) {
    if(req.body.success) {
        if(bat) bat.kill();
    }
    if(!bat) {
        bat = spawn('cmd.exe', ['/c App.exe']);
        bat.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
            res.end(JSON.stringify({error: true, message: data.toString()}));
        });

        bat.on('exit', function (code) {
            bat = null;
            console.log('Child exited with code ' + code);
            res.end(JSON.stringify({error: false, message: "Application Closed!"}));
        });
    }
    bat.stdin.write(req.body.input+'\n');
    bat.stdout.once('data', function (data) {
        console.log(data.toString());
        res.end(JSON.stringify({error: false, message: data.toString()}));
    });
});
```

Problem is that on success when I kill child process child process gets killed but App.exe keeps running. I there any way to stop App.exe from running

Comment: Instead of `cmd.exe`, can't you start `App.exe` directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of spawning `cmd.exe` which spawns `App.exe`, you can spawn the latter directly:

```
bat = spawn('App.exe');
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to kill a spawned process in node.js you need to use the `SIGINT`.

```
bat.kill('SIGINT');
```

A list of all the POSIX signals and what they do can be found at [signal7](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)

Comment: I tried it, it did not work. It killed child process but app.exe was keep running. thanks for your reply